# GTEST: reset previous GetParam() values

Tags: c++, c, googletest, parameterized

I am writting one parameterized test using GTEST framework. I want to reset the previous values passed to TEST_P via GetParam().
In below code gp.expected should return 0, 1, 0, but its returning 0, 1, 1

Code snipet:

```
class TestInput
{
public:
bool validate;
int  input;
int  expected;

TestInput(bool validate, int input, int expected)
{        
    this->validate = validate;
    this->input = input;
    this->expected = expected;
}    
};

    //[TRIMMED THE CODE] ...

   TEST_P(TestCase, nameTest)
   {
    TestInput gp = GetParam();
    printf("\n %d,", gp.expected); //Output 0,1,1 ???
   }

#define TestCase_TestData \
::testing::Values( \
TestInput(TRUE, 0, 0), \
TestInput(FALSE, 0, 1), \
TestInput(FALSE, 0, 0) \
)
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(TestCase, TestCase, TestCase_TestData);
```

Thanks in advance

Pritish

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me just using lower case literals for booleans, i.e. standard values.

Make sure you are not `using namespace ::testing;` so that your `TestCase` collides with `::testing::TestCase`.